# How to access anaconda libraries on a Jupyter notebook on MacOS?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, anaconda, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to MacOS, and first time using Anaconda- I've installed Anaconda successfully and am able to read all the packages installed via `conda list`. I run python via Jupyter, but when I open Jupyter via cmd:`Jupyter notebook`, I'm not able to import some of the packages that conda lists as already installed. I've read that anaconda automatically uses a virtualenv- so I'm not familiar with how virtual environments work as well- I tried launching Jupyter from the anaconda directory- but the problem persists.

How can I access anaconda via Jupyter notebooks ?

PS: I even opened the Anaconda navigator GUI and launched Jupyter notebook from there- still I'm not able to load those libraries

PS2: I checked `virtualenv --version` and got `command not found` so I guess virtualenv isn't installed or used? This is a new machine and I've just installed anaconda and nothing else- not even a fresh copy of python-assuming that python comes inbuilt in the os.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, a Jupyter notebook should be able to use all packages you see with `conda list`. What does `conda info --envs` show?

You can activate a specific environment by doing `source activate 'env-name'` and then start a `jupyter notebook` from there.